# is Barcode API Overview Free in the Google Vision API?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am unable to find the Pricing for the BarcodeReader API in the Google Vision. I am not sure whether the API is free or is there any pricing for that?

If anyone has used it previously, Please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the ML Kit and so it might be charged by text-detection; see [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing).

Comment: I have gone through that already but Barcode Reader is not mentioned anywhere. How to be sure?

Comment: "ML Kit also provides APIs to perform face detection, barcode scanning, inference using custom ML models, and more, all on the device, without requiring a network call." If the network Call is not required then How will count the reuqests?